# How to send same headers for whole Spring Framework controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Specifically, I want whole controlerer to send "Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*".

I've tried below but that doesn't seem to work:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/controller/base", headers="Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*")
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/blah", produces = application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public Map blah(/*...,*/ HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        //...
    }
}
```

It only work when I explicitly set (in all methods) like that:

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Any way to somehow set this for one or more controllers in a single place?

Comment: I might be mistaken but aren't you mixing up request and response? Adding the "headers" attribute to the @RequestMapping only imply that incoming requests are filtered so that only those who have the expected header actually end up in your controller...

Comment: To achieve what you're trying to do, I guess you'll have to go for writing either a Spring interceptor, or a servlet filter, so that you can manipulate the response object before it is returned to the client.

Comment: I'm developing for PhoneGap and so a Firefox addon https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/forcecors/ and PhoneGap whitelisting options work for me ;-) http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to intercept all methods of a controller from the controller itself (except for ugly hacks such as using `@InitBinder`).

However, you can create a `HandlerInterceptor` and apply it to the base URL of your controller. For example, using `@EnableMvc`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MyWebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(...).addPathPatterns("/controller/base/**");
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [@ControllerAdvice annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#new-in-3.2-webmvc-controller-advice) introduced in Spring 3.2, combined with @InitBinder.

> > "Classes annotated with @ControllerAdvice can contain @ExceptionHandler, @InitBinder, and @ModelAttribute methods and those will apply to @RequestMapping methods across controller hierarchies as opposed to the controller hierarchy within which they are declared. @ControllerAdvice is a component annotation allowing implementation classes to be auto-detected through classpath scanning."

- Set the response header in the method annotated with `@InitBinder`.
- Annotate the class with `@ControllerAdvice` to have it process the @InitBinder globally.